# making one pyd for a set of files with cython

Tags: cython

I have multiple .py files in one package

```
packageA
    \__init__.py
    \mod1.py
    \mod2.py
    \mod3.py
```

can I config cython to compile and then packing them all in one `packageA.pyd` ?

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would better turn all the `.py` files into `.pyx`, then include them into the main `.pyx` of the Cython extension:

`packageA.pyx`:

```
include "mod1.pyx" 
include "mod2.pyx" 
include "mod3.pyx"
```

Then, compile using a `setup.py` looking like:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

setup(
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = [
        Extension("packageA", sources=["packageA.pyx"])
    ]
)
```

Running this would generate an all in one `packageA.pyd` binary file.
Of course, this will output a single module named `packageA`, and I don't know if this is acceptable for you, or if you really need distinct modules in your package.
But there might be other ways that better fit your question...

Comment: no need to turn all to .pyx just include them with .py extension will work fine.

Comment: @wtayyeb Yes, you're right. I saw that later. After having read you next question about Cython. Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: Is theere any way to in mod1.py do relative import of module mod2.py?